# How to take 2 user inputs and store them in a variable in Python?

Tags: python

I need to take 2 user inputs and turn them into a list and further into variables.

I have a starting command which I can ignore by splitting the message with

```
user_input = str(message.content).split('!command ')
```

but the outcome is `['', 'input1, input2']` and I need the whole thing to be seperated like `['', 'input1', 'input2']` so I can take the inputs with indexing and further work with them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this ( it's a bit dirty but it works):

```
data = '!command input1, input2'
inputs = data.split('!command ')[-1].split(', ') #to get inputs
```

But why there is a comma between input 1 and 2 ?
Is it better if the command is :

```
'!command input1 input2'
```

You can split by space and then get inputs.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
user_input = str(message.content).split('!command ')
user_input = [y for x in user_input for y in x.split(', ')]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to assign them to separate variables in one line:

```
input1, input2 = str(message.content).split('!command ')[1].split(', ')
```